# Belkin 450 wireless Router can't access specific websites

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have a Belkin 450 router that connects my internet to my laptop computer. It will work for 24 hours then all of a sudden I can't access google.com any antivirus website sysinternals website or anything like that. I will take it back to walmart and get another Belkin router it will work for 24 hours and then once again I can't access the same websites. I have another device which is a TV and the same websites can't be accessed on either device

Any ideas ?

Comment: Sounds more like malware infection on the computer... especially with this quote "I have another device which is a TV that connects to netflix and I can connect to netflix on my TV but not on my computer."

Comment: I would agree but why would buying a new router make it go away for 24 hours .... and so far I have found no malware

Comment: To connect the new router, what exact steps are you taking?  Is one of them restarting the computer?  If not, what steps are you taking to get the computer to access the new router?   The point being one of the steps to hooking up the new could be buying you a good connection for X amount of time.

Comment: I just plug in the new router and connect over wireless

Comment: "and connect over wireless" --- what happens if you disconnect and forget the wireless connection, then reconnect from scratch?

Comment: ok so I was wrong TV and Router do the same thing and if I connect my internet directly to the laptop without the router it works fine